# There is any way to check if the function was executed? javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a script that gets a button from a webpage and then send it through discord using a webhook. My problem is that the script is a loop that it is checking all the time if the buttons exits. So, when the button exits it spams a lot the discord webhook. Is there is any way to stop spamming?

```js
myFunction()

function myFunction() {
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  var min = 30,
    max = 50;
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)

  if (button[0]) {
    console.log("%c Button!", "color: green;")

    //here will go the webhook to send the discord message
  }

  console.log('Waiting ' + rand + ' secs');
  setTimeout(myFunction, rand * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Move the last 2 lines into an `else` block?

Comment: what @JohnnyMopp said, or you could instead of calling a function reccursively with set timeout use a setInterval and clear the returned interval once the condition was satisfied

Comment: @JohnnyMopp has the answer. But why the random timeout ?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what it is that you'd like to happen? Do you want your script to send something to Discord when a user clicks the button? Do you want the script to send a message on a timer? Your code doesn't really explain what you're trying to do as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `else` condition:

```js
function myFunction()
{
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
    if (button[0])
    {
        console.log("%c Button!", "color: green;")

        //here will go the webhook to send the discord message
    } else {
        var min = 30, max = 50;
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        console.log('Waiting ' + rand + ' secs');
        setTimeout(myFunction, rand * 1000);
    }
}

myFunction();
```

Or you could use `setInterval` if you wanted a non-random time between function calls:

```js
var intervalId = window.setInterval(
  function()
  {
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
    if (button[0])
    {
      console.log("%c Button!", "color: green;")
      window.clearInterval( intervalId );
      //here will go the webhook to send the discord message
    }
  },
  1000
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an interval and clear it when the button exists

```js
function myFunction() {
  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  if (button) {
    clearTimeout(tId)
    console.log("%c Button!", "color: green;")
    //here will go the webhook to send the discord message
  }
}
const tId = setInterval(myFunction, 1000)
```